# Question about word order for emphasis

Tags: meaning, translation

I am a student of the English language, and also Psychology. If I were to translate **Rational Emotional Behavioral Therapy**, should the emphasis (the first and most important word) be on *Behavioral*, *Emotional* or in *Rational*?

Comment: Why would one of these words be more important than the others?

Comment: If I am not wrong, behavioral therapy is more common and heard than the other two. Rather than its being "rational therapy + emotional therapy + behavioral therapy", it could be 'behavioural therapy' with other two attributes. It's scope for different interpretation too.

Comment: I have Ph.D. in psych, but a different area. As jargon, I'd hug close to the original. These are terms of art, not just descriptions that one would use in other writing. It's not Therapy that is some combination of Rational, Emotional and Behavioral. "Behavior Therapy" is a thing." "Rational Emotive Behavior Therapy" is a thing. The piece-parts here aren't randomly assembled.

Answer (score 0):

Stress for "behaviour therapy" is as follows (BrE, AmE).

- be'haviour ˌtherapy

As well for "behavioural therapy" the stress pattern is the same.

- be'havioural ˌtherapy

You can listen to it [here](https://www.bing.com/search?q=behavioural+therapy+wiktionary&form=PRFRFR&pc=UE00&httpsmsn=1&msnews=1&refig=9974d9b3ff174f7d909fa5036d895962&sp=-1&pq=behavioural+therapy+wiktionary&sc=0-30&qs=n&sk=&cvid=9974d9b3ff174f7d909fa5036d895962).

Therefore, the compound should be stressed as follows.

- ˌRational Eˌmotional Be'havioral ˌTherapy

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about changing the word order, don't.  Such terminology tends to have defined meanings in the science, and "emotional therapy" or "rational therapy" would have an entirely different meaning from "behavioral therapy".